# Python: find classes in module before class is defined

Tags: python

I have a python class in a module, and I have a few methods within it that need to have a list of certain other classes within the same module.  Here is how I'm doing it right now:

module.py

```
class Main:
  @staticmethod
  def meth1():
    for c in classes:
      #do something

  @staticmethod
  def meth2():
    for c in classes:
      #do something

class Class1:
  pass

class Class2:
  pass

class Class3:
  pass

classes = [Class1, Class3]
```

A few things I would like to improve:

1. I'd like to put the `classes` list somewhere more prevalent.  Ideally, either outside all classes, but at the top of the module file, or as a class attribute of `Main`, but outside of either `meth1` or `meth2`.  The purpose of that is to make it easier to find, if someone needs to add another class definition.
2. If possible, I'd like to do this programmatically so I don't need to explicitly define the list to begin with.  This eliminates the need for #1 (though I'd still like it to be prevalent). To do this, I need a way to list all classes defined within the same module.  The closest I've been able to come is `dir()` or `locals()`, but they also list imported classes, methods, and modules.  Also, I would need some way to identify the classes I want.  I can do that just with an attribute in the classes, but if there's some more elegant way, that would be nice.

Is what I'm trying to do even possible?

Comment: Your example targets two the classes in the module, but then you say you want to programmatically do that.  How would you expect that to work?

Comment: @7stud the idea is that I could add any number of classes, some of which are targeted, some of which are not, and be able to determine whether to target it based on some feature of the class itself.  [here's an example](http://pastebin.com/ALd0YdcU). the problem is 1. I don't know how to `get_all_local_classes()`, and 2. I'd like a better way to filter them than forcing every class to define a `is_a_target()` method.

Comment: @7stud the example above doesn't have any way to do the filter.  I'm looking for suggestions on that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Personally, I would use a [decorator](http://simeonfranklin.com/blog/2012/jul/1/python-decorators-in-12-steps/) to mark the classes that are important. You can place the list that will hold them at the top of the file where it will be noticable.

Here's a simple example:

```
# Classes are added here if they are important, because...
important_classes = []


def important(cls):
    important_classes.append(cls)
    return cls


@important
class ClassA(object):
    pass


class ClassB(object):
    pass


@important
class ClassC(object):
    pass

# Now you can use the important_classes list however you like.
print(important_classes)
# => [<class '__main__.ClassA'>, <class '__main__.ClassC'>]
```

Comment: Ah! This is exactly what I was lookin for.

Comment: I just fixed a bug, @ewok, I forgot to return `cls` from the decorator.

Answer (score 2):

You can use inspect.

First, get the list of local variables:

```
local_vars = locals().values()
```

Then we need to inspect each one:

```
import inspect
local_vars = [i for i in local_vars if inspect.isclass(i)]
```

To get only classes locally defined, check if `cls.__module__ == __name__` as follows:

```
def get_classes():
    global_vars = list(globals().values())
    classes = [i for i in global_vars if inspect.isclass(i)]
    return [i for i in classes if i.__module__ == __name__]
```

The overall idea is this: [inspect](https://docs.python.org/2/library/inspect.html) allows you to inspect live objects, and iterating over all local variables allows you to inspect everything within your current namespace. The final part, which classes are defined locally, can be done by checking if the module name is the same as the current namespace, or `cls.__module__ == __name__`.

Finally, for Python3 compatibility, I've added `list(globals().values()`, since the dictionary size will change during list comprehension. For Python2, since `dict.values()` returns a list, this can be omitted.

EDIT:

For further filtering, you can also use specific class attributes or other, as was mentioned in the comments. This is great if you are worried about restructuring your module into a package later.

```
def get_classes(name='target'):
    global_vars = list(globals().values())
    classes = [i for i in global_vars if inspect.isclass(i)]
    return [i for i in classes if hasattr(i, name)]
```

Comment: would this not also include imported classes?

Comment: I gave it a try.  It does include imported classes.  it doesn't include `inspect` because `inspect` is a module, not a class

Comment: Wow, I need to have coffee. Sorry. Let me play with this a bit.

Comment: Sorry updated to filter for only locally defined classes. I added a check for `cls.__module__`, which you to find all classes defined in a module programmatically and not imported elsewhere.

Comment: can you explain why you shifted from using `locals()` to `globals()`?

Comment: @ewok, both work, just locals() would not work within a function definition. Then, locals() would produce nothing, since the local namespace is empty.

Comment: marked this as the answer.  To do filtering, I added an attribute called `target` to the classes I want to target, and added `[i for i in classes if hasattr(i, 'target')]` before returning.  can you add those?

Comment: Edited and done. I also added a practical use case for such.

Answer (score 2):

There may be better ways to achieve this, but I would make all of these subclasses of a holder, then use `__subclasses__()` to pull them all:

```
class Main:
    def meth1(self):
        for c in Holder._subclasses__():
            #do something

    def meth2(self):
        for c in Holder._subclasses__():
            #do something

class Holder(object):
    pass

class Class1(Holder):
    pass

class Class2(Holder):
    pass

class Class3(Holder):
    pass
```

You could even make them subclasses of `Main` if you wanted to, and then pull them with a classmethod:

```
class Main(object):
    @classmethod
    def meth1(cls):
        for c in cls._subclasses__():
            #do something

class Class1(Main): pass
```

You do need to inherit from `object` with Python 2 for this to work.

Answer (score 2):

Your list seems to be targeting a subset of the available classes in the module, so at some point you will have to specify the classes you are targeting.

```
import sys

target_classes = ["Class1", "Class3"]

class Main:
    def __init__(self, classes):
        self.target_classes = classes

    def meth1(self):
        for s in self.target_classes:
            C = getattr(sys.modules[__name__], s)
            C().speak()

    def meth2(self):
        for c in classes:
            print c
            #do something

class Class1:
    def speak(self):
        print "woof"

class Class2:
    def speak(self):
        print "squeak"

class Class3:
    def speak(self):
        print "meow"


Main(target_classes).meth1()

--output:--
woof
meow
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this is the best practice, but this will do what you need:

```
class Main:
    def __init__(self, locals):
        self.classes = []
        for (c, val) in locals.iteritems():
            try:
                if c[:5] == 'Class':
                    self.classes.append(val)
            except:
                pass

    def meth1(self):
        for c in self.classes:
            pass

    def meth2(self):
        for c in self.classes:
            pass

class Class1:
    pass

class Class2:
    pass

class Class3:
    pass

main = Main(locals())
print main.classes
```

Comment: semi-useful.  It works for instances, but not if `meth1` and `meth2` are static.  I should have included that and I'll update the question.

Answer (score 0):

In current versions of Python you can use:

```
from __future__ import annotations
```